# Jquery adding and removing elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add and remove a span element dynamically. it's throwing syntax errors like

> expected ')' and expected ';'

please help me to fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[data-required='true']").focus(function () {
            $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'red' }).after("<span class="label_error;"style="color:red;font-size:10pt">This field is required</span>");
        });

    $("input[data-required='true']").blur(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'white' }).remove("<span class="label_error;"style="color:red;font-size:10pt">This field is required</span>") ;
    });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues. Firstly you need to use different quotes to delimit the string to those you use within the string. Helpfully, in JS you can use either single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes to achieve the same purpose. Also, the `class` attribute should not have a trailing `;`. It can be helpful to use a text editor which has syntax highlighting as it makes it nearly impossible to miss mistakes like that.

Your second problem is that the `remove()` method expects a selector, not a whole HTML string. To remove the `span` which was appended in the `focus` event, use `next()` to select it, then `remove()`. Try this:

```js
$("input[data-required='true']").focus(function () {
    $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'red' }).after('<span class="label_error" style="color: red; font-size: 10pt">This field is required</span>');
});

$("input[data-required='true']").blur(function () {
    $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'white' }).next('span').remove();
});
```

Finally, note that it is *much* better practice to define your styles in CSS as it separates the HTML/JS from the styling rules, and helps make the JS shorter as well. Try this:

```css
input[data-required='true'] {
    background-color: white; /* transparent may work here too */
}
input[data-required='true']:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
span.label_error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```js
$("input[data-required='true']").focus(function () {
    $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).next('span').remove();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/u6azsL7q/)

Answer (score 3):

The way that you are concatenating the values in your HTML string is wrong,

```
.after("<span class='label_error' style='color:red;font-size:10pt;'>" +
         "This field is required" +
        "</span>");
```

To fix this issue either you can use `single quote` in your string wrapped by double quotes or try to escape the double quote by using `\` like `"avi\"s code is wrong"`.

On top of all, the best approach would be creating element by using jquery,

```
.after($("<span>", {class : 'label_error', 
                    style : 'color:red;font-size:10pt;',
                    text : 'This field is required'
                   }));
```

This would be more readable and maintainable. And I forgot to spot another one error that you made in your code. You are using `.remove()` in a wrong way,

```
$("input[data-required='true']").blur(function () {
   $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'white' }).next("span.label_error").remove();
});
```

You have to select the relevant element from your `$(this)` object and invoke remove over it.

---

And the best approach for finishing up your task is, allot the styling works to be done to the css by writing rules with relevant selectors (said by @rory)

```
input[data-required='true'] {
  background-color: white;
}
input[data-required='true']:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
span.label_error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

And the js would be,

```
var errorMsg = $("<span>", {class: 'label_error',text: 'This field is required'});

$("input[data-required='true']").focus(function() {
  $(this).after(errorMsg);
}).blur(function() {
  $(this).next("span.label_error").remove();
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/u6azsL7q/1/)