# Select element and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is a follow up question to [Jquery adding and removing elements dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224792/jquery-adding-and-removing-elements-dynamically).
I am trying to display "this field is required" next to select element only when nothing is selected like when value=" " in select element.how do i do this?

HTML

```
<input data-required="true" type="text" name="foo" />
<select data-required="true" >
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
$("input[data-required='true'],select[data-required='true']").focus(function() {

  $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');

}).blur(function() {
  $(this).next('span').remove();
}).keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).next('span').remove();
  } else {
    $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
  }
});
```

css

```
input[data-required='true'] {
  background-color: white;
  /* transparent may work here too */
}

input[data-required='true']:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

span.label_error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Comment: Note that this question has been [raised for Meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319801/unclear-what-youre-asking-close-vote-without-comment) by one of your answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `html` `<label>` element with `for` attribute set, `required` attribute set at `input type="text"` , `select` element;  `css` `:focus`, `:invalid`, `:not()` , `:checked`, `:first-child` pseudo selectors,   adjacent sibling selector `+`

```css
[data-required]:focus:invalid + [for] {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50px;
}
.label_error,
[data-required]:focus:not(:checked) option:first-child,
[data-required]:not(:focus) + [for] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input data-required="true" type="text" name="foo" id="foo" value="" required />
  <label for="foo" class="label_error">This field is required</label>
  <br>
  <select data-required="true" name="car" id="car" required>
    <option></option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <label for="car" class="label_error">This field is required</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .val() on a select list, just like with an input:

```
if($(this).val()=="") 
    $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have only changed the javascript.

```js
$("input[data-required='true']").focus(function() {
  $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
}).blur(function() {
  $(this).next('span').remove();
}).keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).next('span').remove();
  } else {
    $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
  }
});

$("select").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() !== "") {
    $(this).next("span").remove();
  }
})

$("select").focus(function() {
  $(this).next("span").remove();
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
  }
})

$("select").blur(function() {
  $(this).next("span").remove();
})
```

```css
input[data-required='true'] {
  background-color: white;
  /* transparent may work here too */
}

input[data-required='true']:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

span.label_error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-required="true" type="text" name="foo" />
<select data-required="true" >
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into answer like this using change event handler. just changed javascript.

```
$("input[data-required='true'],select[data-required='true']").focus(function() {

  $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');

}).blur(function() {
  $(this).next('span').remove();
}).change(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).next('span').remove();
  } else {
    $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
  }
}).keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).next('span').remove();
  } else {
    $(this).after('<span class="label_error">This field is required</span>');
  }
});
```

Comment: In reply to your comment *"thanks i will delete this question. i thought stack don't like deleting questions. thats why i didn't "*, rubbish questions, questions with a trivial typographical error, or questions like yours which are caused by a silly mistake, *are* deleted all the time. Only deleting questions that are useful for future readers, especially if they have useful answers, is frowned upon.